# Importing a CSV into SQL Server - Truncation

Tags: sql-server, import

I'm trying to import data into SQL Server using SQL Server Management Studio and I keep getting the "output column... failed because truncation occurred" error. This is because I'm letting the Studio autodetect the field length which it isn't very good at.

I know I can go back and extend the column length but I'm thinking there must be a better way to get it right first time without having to manaully work out how long each column is.

I know that this must be a common issue but my Google searches aren't coming up with anything as I'm more looking for a technique rather than a specific issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach you may take, assuming the import is not something which would take hours to complete, is to just set every text column to `VARCHAR(MAX)`, and then complete the CSV import.  Once you have the actual table in SQL Server, you can inspect each column using `LEN` to see how wide it is.  Based on that, you can either alter columns, or you could just take notes, drop the table, and reimport using appropriate widths.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it sounds helpful but hopefully someone else has another technique that involves a less manual approach. Maybe there is a program that will scan a csv and produce a "CREATE TABLE" command with the *correct* values?

Comment: You can certainly write such a script yourself.  Maybe someone else knows of a tool which can already do this.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into leveraging SSIS for this task. There is somewhat of a fixed cost in terms of spending time setting up the process for importing the csv file and creating a physical table in the database. Ultimately, though, you will be able to set the data types for each column/field in your file. Further, SSIS will enable you to transform or reformat the data to say the least.

I would suggest downloading Visual Studio and SQL Server Data Tools. The latter contains the necessary tools, including SSIS, SSRS, and SSAS, for which you would need to complete this task.

The main point is being able to automate this task, especially if it's an ongoing project of uploading csv files into the database.